# flutter image picker from app internal images not from gallery or camera

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I've made a profile page and now I wanna when the user wants to change the profile image, instead of choosing a picture from a gallery or camera, pick an image from my default avatars?

is there any widget or package?

Comment: I don't thing there is plugin like this .what you can do is you can add bunch of images in the assets then you can create a list and how them in the listview in vertical or horizontal fasion and then one select you can perform the further actions.

Comment: you can check this one https://pub.dev/packages/multiavatar

Comment: you can use this plugin to get the avatars.